# How to run gitlab-runner as a service?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

After installing gitlab-runner, I have to do

```
gitlab-runner run
```

and leave it open. When I reboot, I have to run it again.

Is there a reason for this? I thought maybe `start` would start it as a service so it would run forever, but

```
gitlab-runner start
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=215405 revision=32fc1585 version=15.2.1
FATAL: The --user is not supported for non-root users
```

I can't use `sudo` because then it won't find virtualbox images which are for non sudo

Comment: Did you ever find the correct solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I beleive you should register the gitlab-runner executable as a service using `systemctl`.

For example, as described in [this gitlab forum thread](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/runner-not-running-as-service/92671/6) :

```
systemctl enable gitlab-runner
systemctl restart gitlab-runner
```